# Is it possible to use <img> as a full background image without javascript?

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

When I use an image as `background-image` with `cover` property I get a full screen image with perfect ratios. Is it possible to get same result with `img`, without javascript?

I would like to create a parallax background. When the user scroll the content below the image slides over the image.

The problem is with the size of the image, I added `width: 100%`, but it doesn't work as the `background-size: cover`. Should I increase the width? What is the best practice?

[The JSFiddle version is available here.](http://jsfiddle.net/eLLL5e13/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    function contentHeight() {
     var wheight = $(window).height();
        $('#content').css({
         'margin-top' : wheight
        });
    }
    
    contentHeight();
    
    $(window).resize(function(){
     contentHeight();
    });
});
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

#image {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#image img {
    width: 100%;
}

#content {
    background: #ccc;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image"><img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg"></div>
<div id="content">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Did not understand the question. `background-size: cover` is already *without JS*. Could you clarify more?

Comment: Sorry, I would like same result with IMG.

Comment: Is an answer using JS acceptable then? It'll be a whole lot of work trying to use media queries for this.

Comment: I'm using javascript to setup the margin-top, because the #image is fixed. The most important thing is to use <img>, not background-image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to emulate `background-size: cover` with an `img` tag you can do that with the css property `object-fit` and the value `cover`. [You can check support here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit) - *note* it is limited (no MS support at the moment).

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eLLL5e13/2/)**

You can emulate `background-size: cover` with pure css, by simply setting the `img` `height` and `width` to `auto`; this will preserve the aspect ration of the `img`. But it will not center the `img` perfect, so an easy fix is to add a few rules to make sure it is sitting in the middle of the parent container; make sure the parent has `overflow: auto`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/prvzqwbr/2/)**

You can see a comparison between `background-size: cover` and the second technique here: **[COMPARISON](http://jsfiddle.net/prvzqwbr/)**

For this specific `img` the second technique is acceptable, but once if the image size varies to any degree, issues will become present, [as you can see in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prvzqwbr/3/).

Comment: Nice idea but apparently not very usable yet. Too bad you added something incorrect afterwards.

Comment: @Shikkediel, yeah that's right, I've added another demo of how to do something similar without a universally accept CSS rule

Comment: That's not gonna work the same though. I liked the answer a lot more before that was added...

Comment: @Shikkediel can you elaborate why the second option is not feasible?

Comment: Because it's doesn't imitate `cover` when the aspect ratio of the screen is relatively higher than the image.

Comment: @Shikkediel I get your point but, I'm not sure perfect emulation should be expected when you're unwilling or incapable of using certain properties or tools (`js`). Just need to go with the "best" option at that point

Comment: Seems using JS is acceptable but I like the first part. So I won't be petty and upvote again.

Comment: Unfortunately when the window's height is small the ratio is incorrect. It looks like the only option is the javascript.

Comment: See my updated answer, the only current alternative without JS is putting the image inside `svg` tags.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the only cross browser alternative without JS would be to inline an `svg` and use `<image>` :

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvyQJQ?editors=110)

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 800 531" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
 <image xlink:href="/path/image.jpg" width="800" height="531"/>
</svg>
```

```
svg {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
}
```

The `svg` can be given any size but `viewbox` and original dimensions of `<image>` have to be defined.

The trick is in the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute :

[Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio)

---

I also wrote a little script for this using the aspect ratio of a regular image and some transforms :

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/Shikkediel/pen/MaGbbp)

```
<div id="wrap">
 <img id="layer" src="/path/image.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

```
#wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wrap img {
  position: relative;
}

.wide {
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}

.tall {
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}
```

```
$(function() {

var parent = $('#wrap'),
tableau = $('#layer'),
proportion = 800/531; // aspect ratio of the image

$(window).on('load resize', coverSpace);

function coverSpace() {

    var range = parent.width(),
    term = parent.height(),
    broad = term*proportion,
    aerial = range/proportion;

    if (range/term >= proportion) tableau.css({width: '100%', height: aerial}).attr('class', 'wide');
    else tableau.css({width: broad, height: term}).attr('class', 'tall');
}
});
```

Comment: This seems to preserve aspect ratio, but I am curious why it is superior to just having `height: auto` and `width: auto`? Is it because it rescales the image, rather than cropping? Care to add you method to my comparison so we can compare? [comparison](http://jsfiddle.net/prvzqwbr/)

Comment: actually, it obvious this is the superior solution when `object-fit` and `background-size` are not useable; on large images, the `inline-img` technique exposes [many issues](http://jsfiddle.net/prvzqwbr/3/)

Comment: Still trying to inspect what you've put together there exactly but from a first glance I'd think the biggest difference is that the image itself it resized to the parent and cropped correctly under all circumstances with the above code, independent of aspect ratio as well. Fiddle doesn't look very size responsive...

Comment: The basic idea of using transforms looks the same though, the answer is just using a bit of JS to adapt size and switch to imitate cover when the "breaking point" of the aspect ratio has been reached. I had thought about a media query approach as well but that seems circumventive and doesn't really increase browser support more than either of the above options anyway. If it were possible at all.

Comment: On the last line, instead of `height: term` the following could also be used : `height: '100%'`. The current code is just more convenient for when `window` is the parent and no height was inherited.

Comment: I was using the `transforms` to center the image on the canvas and used the wrapper as that canvas rather than the `section`, in case their sizes varied. If it was me, I would use `js` or make adjustments to use `background-size`; hopefully soon `object-fit` will be universal

Comment: Could be a while, knowing Microsoft especially... and then there's retro browser support. Not everybody updates often. But there's always feature testing and fallbacks of course for when basic support is decent.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse it is:

Use this CSS

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

#image {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#image img {

    height:100%;
    width:auto;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eLLL5e13/7/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I would like same result with IMG, without background css property. Please try my demo, and you will see what's my problem.